# Is there an isomorphism between factor groups and subgroups of symmetric groups?

Tags: group-theory

If H is a subgroup of G ( | G:H |=n, n > 1), then how can you show that G has a factor group G/N which is isomorphic to a subgroup D of the symmetric group Sn with |D| > 1.

I've been looking at Cayley's Theorem but it's not specific to the factor groups.

Comment: Are $H$ and $N$ the same subgroup? Is $N$ normal?

Answer (score 2):

Here's something along the lines of what I think you want, though I don't think you are using $G/N$ in the sense of [quotient group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group):

Let $G$ act on the left cosets of $H$ by left multiplication. Then this action defines a nontrivial permutation representation $\phi: G\rightarrow S_{n}$. We use $S_n$ because the action permutes the $n$ cosets of $H$, as $|G:H|=n$. Perhaps you can see how to get what you want from here.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's specifically looking at the factor/quotient group having an isomorphic map to a subgroup of Sn

Comment: If we want the factor quotient group to exist, then we must presume that $H$ is a normal subgroup. Now $G/H$ is a group of order $n$. Now let $G/H$ act on itself by left multiplication. Now, apply Cayley's theorem to conclude that $G/H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.